# OpenOCD - handle disconnected target

Tags: c#, tcl, stm32, openocd

I want to start and control OpenOCD from a C# application via its TCL interface. The communication works fine in general, but now I am dealing with a single corner case - the situation when the user wants to download firmware, but forgets to connect or power on the programmed target.

When I start OpenOCD without microprocessor or programmer connected, OpenOCD startup fails, the program exits and doesn't open its TCL interface at all. On the other hand when I disconnect the programmer when OpenOCD is already running, OpenOCD waits for the programmer connection and keeps TCL interface working. I start OpenOCD with the following command and my targets are STM32F3xx microcontrollers:

```
openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f3x.cfg
```

I tried to read the return code in the case when OpenOCD immediately exits, but code 1 is returned when no target is connected but also when another program instance is running, so this method is not very accurate.

So how can I distinguish between OpenOCD startup failure and unavailable target errors?

Comment: Does the program produce diagnostic information on standard error? That's a common POSIX way to distinguish different problems.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Parsing of stderr will definitely help me, although it is not very comfortable - the program output is more like a log file than a simple error message.